# Can I trace malicious email sent through a cloud hosting service?

Tags: email, cloud-computing, phone, user-tracking, web-hosting

Around the time my phone started acting like it was hacked, I was sent a suspicious email that opened automatically into a website without clicking on anything. I tracked it to a cloud hosting service. It started there and went through two other IP addresses (with no information available on who from or location) before being delivered to me. The original message with header also notes some bouncing and whitelistcomplaints. Is there any way I can find more information on where this email came from and what it might have done to my cell phone (Windows phone)?

Comment: If the hacker was smart then all the information you will be tracking down will probably be spooofed or not authentic. I think it would be a waste of time to put more than an hour looking into it. But to answer you question of if there is anyway to find out more I suppose you can do a whois lookup on the IP address but again it probably isn't going to lead very far considering most email headers from spammers and hackers are spoofed